# How to make remote endless-scroll (infinite-scroll) with ajax?

Tags: json, ajax

I have JSON like:

```
{
    "nextToken": "aGFsYW1hbj03NT0xNDkxMTI0NTA1", // token for next query
    "results": [
        {
            "id": 100
        },
        {
            "id": 102
        },
        ...
    ]
}
```

how to parse to HTML and use endless scroll using data `nextToken` form JSON?
Search about it, but not found.
Just found with `id` selector in html not data from `json`. Have you idea ?

Comment: You must use javascript

Comment: You have a demo code @MarcoSalerno ?

Comment: What do you mean with endless scroll?

Comment: infinite scroll ..

Comment: Infinite scroll doesn't mean anything

Answer (score 0, accepted):

thanks for comment @MarcoSalemo.
I have solve my problem :
just use table with structure like this :

```
    <table id="myTable" data-next="">
        <tbody>
        </tbody>
    </table>
```

then ajax like this :

```
// call `data-next` from table    
var next = $('#myTable').data("next");
$.ajax({
        url: url, 
        dataType: 'json',
        data: {'next': next},
        type: 'GET',
        success: function(data) {
            var i = 0;
            $( data.results ).each(function() {
                $('#myTable > tbody').append('<tr><td>'+data.results[i].id+'</td></tr>');

            i += 1;
        });

        // update `data-next` from json into table
        $( "#myTable" ).data( "next", data.next );
    }
});
```

and then call ajax from scroll event to make endless-scroll (infinite scroll) ..